# Exporting classified land cover class as an asset for NDVI calculations

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi, land-classification, random-forest

I have conducted a supervised classification in Google Earth Engine using Random Forest, to which I have provided the code.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3b3d4583f26a4651f4fbe10aa80c5f30

```
Map.addLayer(roi, {color: 'black'}, 'ROI');
Map.centerObject(roi,8);
Map.setOptions('satellite');

//Landsat data includes a 'pixel_qa' band which can be used to create a function to mask clouds

function maskClouds(image) {
    var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
    var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(5).int();  
    var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)); 
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

//Adding Spectral Indices

// This function maps spectral indices for Mangrove Mapping using Landsat 8 Imagery

var addIndicesL8 = function(img) {
  // NDVI
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5','SR_B4']).rename('NDVI');
  // NDMI (Normalized Difference Mangrove Index - Shi et al 2016 - New spectral metrics for mangrove forest identification)
  var ndmi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B7','SR_B3']).rename('NDMI');
  // MNDWI (Modified Normalized Difference Water Index - Hanqiu Xu, 2006)
  var mndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3','SR_B6']).rename('MNDWI');
  // SR (Simple Ratio)
  var sr = img.select('SR_B5').divide(img.select('SR_B4')).rename('SR');
  // Band Ratio 54
  var ratio54 = img.select('SR_B6').divide(img.select('SR_B5')).rename('R54');
  // Band Ratio 35
  var ratio35 = img.select('SR_B4').divide(img.select('SR_B6')).rename('R35');
  // GCVI
  var gcvi = img.expression('(NIR/GREEN)-1',{
    'NIR':img.select('SR_B5'),
    'GREEN':img.select('SR_B3')
  }).rename('GCVI');
  return img
    .addBands(ndvi)
    .addBands(ndmi)
    .addBands(mndwi)
    .addBands(sr)
    .addBands(ratio54)
    .addBands(ratio35)
    .addBands(gcvi);
};

//Filter Landsat data by Date and Region

var year = 2021; 
var startDate = (year-1)+'-01-01'; 
var endDate = (year+1)+'-12-31'; 

//Apply filters and masks to Landsat 8 imagery

var l8 = L8.filterDate(startDate,endDate)
// Mask for clouds and cloud shadows
    .map(maskClouds)
//Add the indices
    .map(addIndicesL8);

var composite = l8       
    .median() 
    .clip(roi); 
              
print(composite)

//Mask to areas of low elevation and high NDVI and MNDWI

// Clip SRTM data to region.
var srtmClip = SRTM.clip(roi);

//Mask to elevations less than (lt) 65 meters.
var elevationMask = srtmClip.lt(65);

//Used the NDVI and MNDWI bands to create masks (gt-greater than).
var NDVIMask = composite.select('NDVI').gt(0.25); //areas gt 0.25 highly vegetated
var MNDWIMask = composite.select('MNDWI').gt(-0.50);

//Apply the masks
var compositeNew = composite
   .updateMask(NDVIMask)
   .updateMask(MNDWIMask)
   .updateMask(elevationMask)

//Display results

//Select bands and parameters for visualization.
var visPar = {bands:['SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B4'], min: 1, max: 0.6}; //false colour composite

//Add layer to map.
Map.addLayer(compositeNew.clip(roi), visPar, 'Landsat Composite 2016')

//Construct Random Forest Model 
///Prepare training data and predictors

//After drawing training polygons, merge them together.
var classes = Mangrove.merge(NMangrove)

//Define the bands you want to include in the model.
var bands = ['SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B4','NDVI','MNDWI','SR','GCVI']

//Create a variable called image to select the bands of interest and clip to geometry.
var image = compositeNew.select(bands).clip(roi)

//Assemble samples for the model.
var samples = image.sampleRegions({
    collection: classes, // Set of geometries selected for training
    properties: ['landcover'], // Label from each geometry
    scale: 30 // Make each sample the same size as Landsat pixel
    }).randomColumn('random'); // creates a column with random numbers

//Here we randomly split our samples to set some aside for testing our model's accuracy.
// using the "random" column we created.
var split = 0.8; // Roughly 80% for training, 20% for testing.
var training = samples.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split)); //Subset training data
var testing = samples.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split)); //Subset testing data

//Print these variables to see how much training and testing data you are using.
    print('Samples n =', samples.aggregate_count('.all'));
    print('Training n =', training.aggregate_count('.all'));
    print('Testing n =', testing.aggregate_count('.all'));

//Begin Random Forest Classification.
//.smileRandomForest is used to run the model. Here we run the model using 100 trees
// and 5 randomly selected predictors per split ("(100,5)").
    var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100,5).train({ 
    features: training.select(['SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B4','NDVI','MNDWI','SR','GCVI', 'landcover']), //Train using bands and landcover property
    classProperty: 'landcover', //Pull the landcover property from classes
    inputProperties: bands
    });

//Test the accuracy of the model.
    var validation = testing.classify(classifier);
    var testAccuracy = validation.errorMatrix('landcover', 'classification');
    print('Validation error matrix RF: ', testAccuracy);
    print('Validation overall accuracy RF: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());

//Classify the Landsat composite using the Random Forest model.

var classifiedrf = image.select(bands) 
        .classify(classifier);

var pixelcount = classifiedrf.connectedPixelCount(100, false); 
var countmask = pixelcount.select(0).gt(25); 

var classMask = classifiedrf.select('classification').gt(0)
    var classed= classifiedrf.updateMask(countmask).updateMask(classMask)

print(classed);

//Map results.
//Add classification to map.
Map.addLayer (classed, {min: 1, max: 1, palette:'blue'}, 'Mangrove Extent 2016');

//Calculate Mangrove Area in 2016.

//Use reduceRegion with a Sum reducer to calculate total area.
var get2016 = classed.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(10000).reduceRegion({
      reducer:ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry:roi,
      scale: 60,
      maxPixels:1e13,
      tileScale: 16
      }).get('classification');
      
print(get2016, 'Mangrove Extent 2016 in ha')

/////////////
```

I would like to export my classified mangrove extent as an asset. This is so I can use the classified mangrove extent in a different GEE file to conduct NDVI calculations and create charts.

I have so far been unable to export it with the necessary bands to conduct my NDVI calculations.

How do I do it?

Comment: Please provide the error message(s) as well as the complete code because links tend to not work after some time.

Comment: To export image to asset, you can use [Export.image.toAsset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-toasset).

Comment: Hi @Nikos, I have edited my post to include the code!

Comment: Hi @Padmanabha, I exported the image as an asset, however, when I clip my NDVI composite to it, nothing shows up on the map. I thought I must be going wrong somewhere

Comment: @Erika you did not mention this thing on your question, kindly edit the question. Anyway, the issue may be related to masking. You can try changing the masking conditions. Masking can often creates null images.

Comment: Apologies @Padmanabha! Do you suppose the issue could be the masking after the "//Classify the Landsat composite using the Random Forest model"? At which place within the code would be the best to export the classified image?

Comment: Yes. You can export the classMask directly. If you get null images further, try changing the pixelcount and countmax.